# Cannot delete row from custom tableview cell button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with a custom tableviewCell. In this tableview cell I have a button for deleting a row.

First of all I create this tableview by the following code.

```
   UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = normal;
    [tableView reloadData];
```

I have an appointments array that I use as my datasource. In my cellForRowAtIndex I use the following code to attach my button to an action.

```
 cell.btnDelete.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteAppointment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then I have my action itself.

```
-(void)deleteAppointment:(id) sender{
        NSLog(@"till here");
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"indexpathc: %d",indexPath.row);

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [_exceptions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

It gives back the right index path in my log but it don't delete the row inside my tableview. Can anybody help me?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to update the method `numberOfRowsInSection`. For example if you are keeping your elements in an array, delete one element from it and return updated array in `numberOfRowsInSection`.